# Aligning floating elements to bottom of div

Tags: html, css

Trying to float one ul left and one ul right and keeping them to bottom of div with no success

heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ku2jk/

Comment: you have 4 DIVs :) Which one? the `menubar` ? BTW: `backgroundcolor`  is invalid CSS. and `height =` is also invalid. Should be: `background:` or `background-color` and `height : 100px;`

Comment: sorry typed it up pretty fast should have tested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the approach to float the containers inside another container, which is positioned to the absolute bottom.

You just had some syntax errors plus the container holding the floating divs did not have a width.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ku2jk/26/

```
height = 100px;
       ^   should be height:100px;
backgroundcolor: blue;
          ^  should be background-color;


#menubar{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
       ^   needed a width because positioned absolute.
}
```

Comment: Do i have specify an exact width is there no way to inherit the width from the container?

Comment: I had working with the exact width but i'm trying to make the site adjust depending on browser size

Answer (score 0):

Which divs? Try remove `position: absolute` of `#menubar`. Also, change `backgroundcolor`, that doesn't exist to `background-color` or `background`